# Pascal Compiler returns 'Can't create object file - Error'

Tags: ubuntu, freepascal, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to run a simple Hello World code in Pascal - from the server - using Apache Service Mix. While using it on my local Ubuntu environment - the file executes, and displays the message without any glitches,but while deploying it on the server, and running it from there, the following error is being generated.

> Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4+dfsg-8 [2015/08/14] for x86_64
>   Copyright (c) 1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others Target OS:
>   Linux for x86-64 Compiling C:\store\1464417184459\file.p panna.p(5,1)
>   Error: Can't create object file: C:/store/1464417184459/panna.o
>   panna.p(5,1) Fatal: Can't create object C:/store/1464417184459/file.o
>   Fatal: Compilation aborted Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error
>   exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)

Now, I've looked this up on the Lazarus forum, and the free pascal forum, nothing could help me solve this. 
Also, there are no restrictions on file access, the "C:\..." folder is created on my Desktop, within the Apache Service Mix folder.

Can you please help me figure out where it's that I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, you don't *have* a C: drive!

Comment: It's strange that suddenly the \'s are changed to /, which is unixy, but the driveletter hasn't been changed to a mountpoint. Something is fishy, but I assume it takes a Apache person to sort it out.

Comment: @tripleee - The folder name was just an assignment; I've changed it, and have moved the files into a folder, with a different name. The "C:" path was the default path to save files within the Apache Servicemix folder, on my desktop.